# Can't boot into win11 Stuck in Grub-Win 11 bootloop

Tags: kali-linux, grub2

I have Windows 11 dual boot with Kali linux on my Dell vostro 14 3468 laptop. Didn't had any trouble related to dual boot my Bootloader was Grub2 it had 2 options to boot into Kali or Win11.

While updating some drivers on win11 The grub menu disappeared and system start to boot direct into win11. So i looked it up how to bring grub menu back. I used EasyBCD tool to add Kali linux boot option but when i rebooted it was different it wasn't like previous setups, previously grub was directly loaded now it first load Window Boot Manger and then from there I have to select Kali linux then it launch Grub menu Again with its own Kali and win11 options.

Things were different from previous setup but Everything was fine and i can boot into both Kali and win11. But then I want it to be fixed to i looked it up and set Kali Linux boot option as default in EasyBCD in win11 and set timeout to 0 so it directly load grub. here all the problem started in my opinion I thought by doing this I will load grub from where I can load win11 and Kali linux but I had already set timeout to 0 and made kali default so it went into kind of a loop when try to boot win11.

So, anyone have any idea how to tackle this situation i know about boot repair option via USB but i currently don't have any USB.

Note: I can boot into Kali linux via grub normally

P.s : **Solved** I figured it out that pressing F8 after booting win11 open up Win boot manager

Comment: hint: paragraphs